# Вылетает сессия PHP

Tags: php, сессия

У меня возникла такая проблема. Делаю  на сайте `session_start()`, устанавливаю переменные `$_SESSION`.

При заходе на сайт с другой вкладки сессия слетает.

Как сделать так, чтобы переменные сессии хранились (хотя бы 24 часа) ?

Comment: `При заходе на сайт с другой вкладки` - а разницы в адресах сайта при этом нет? Например, `www.site.ru` и `site.ru`?

Comment: `session_start();` прописан везде ?(где стартует сессия)

Comment: На 24 часа можно и куку повесить.

Answer (score 1):

Косяк явно в вашем коде, и чтобы ткнуть пальцем в проблему нужно видеть данный код, но так как его нету, возможны следующие проблемы, не указан session_start как сказал Malyshev, либо у вас просто идет обнуление, или перезапись какой-то нужной сессии.